# Will RPCs such as Alchemy RPC continue to work seemlessly through the merge?

Tags: cryptography, ethereum, cryptocurrency

I have an application that depends on the reliability of being able to contact the network through Alchemy’s RPC mainnet API.

During the merge, it is crucial that I am able to interact with the PoS chain ASAP. Should I rely on Alchemy’s API for this or do I need a different method or node or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misremembering, *no*. I seem to remember Infura saying that they will have ~12 minutes of downtime around the merge just in case anything goes wrong. I imagine that alchemy will do likewise.

I recommend you run your own geth node.